# What's the motivation for the term "compact" operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, terminology, compactness, compact-operators

I am self-studying functional analysis and have just learned the definition of [compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator). However, it isn't clear to me why the name "compact operator" was chosen.

The operator itself could be considered a one-point subset of a topological vector space of operators, but the "compactness" doesn't seem to refer to any such topology (every operator would constitute a compact subset of such a space, I think).

The definition involves compactness, but only in an indirect way (*bounded* sets get mapped to *relatively compact* subsets). Thus it is unclear to me if there is a good reason for the term.

Comment: Well, the reason is precisely that bounded subsets map to relatively compact sets. There isn't any more reason to it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802255/compute-the-spectrum-of-non-compact-operator

See the answer to this question.

Comment: What's the motivation behind the term "bounded linear operator"? Bounded sets get mapped to bounded sets. I think "compact linear operator" just strengthens "bounded linear operator" by saying that bounded sets get mapped not only to merely bounded sets, but to (pre)compact sets.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as my professor says, compact operators are small and Fredholm operators are big since cokernel of a Fredholm operator should be finite dimensional while the image of a compact operator between Banach spaces can not contain an infinite dimensional closed subspace.

There is also a deeper connection between two of those types of operators which is a subject of Riesz--Schauder theory.

Comment: Image of a compact operator can be infinite-dimensional. Take any integral operator with bounded kernel.

Comment: @Wojowu To be more formal, the image of a compact operator between Banach spaces  can not contain an infinite dimensional closed subspace.

Comment: Then you should edit the answer in order to clarify that. As written it is straight up wrong.

Comment: @Wojowu Sure, no problem

Comment: I think now that this has been corrected it offers some useful intuition. The answer in the linked comment also has good intuition. Going to leave this question open for a bit to see if others have more input.

Comment: @WillG yeah, since the standard answer was also provided in the comment, it’s interesting to see if there are some unusual opinions.